# What type of cement (grout) to use when fixing pool tiles and walls?

Tags: tile, pool, grout, cement

The cement in between the tiles on my pool is breaking, also, some parts of the wall near the pool are also breaking.

I'm a total newbie regarding cement and similar materials, so I'm at a loss on what to use where and how in order to fix these issues.

Here are the tiles that are losing "something". What to use to close the gaps?

[image: Tiles]

Here is the wall that's cracking, it has this "sand" or "quartz" like material as they usually do in pools - what would be a nice thing to close this crack with to prevent further damage? I'm not really worried that it won't perfectly look like the original. The goal is to prevent and reduce further damage.

[image: Wall]

Comment: Terminology: "cement in between the tiles" - is called **grout**

Comment: Thanks! As I said, total newbie here :)

Comment: Go to a hardware store and asking for masonry grout.

Comment: What about the wall crack?